# SQL Server 2008 collation conflict

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, collation

This was the strange error I face in my stored procedure ,

> Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AI"
>   and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation. Severity
>   16 State 9
>   on debugging I see problem was in the join between two tables where one table was getting filled by a temp table. strange thing is this I did not get the error on my testing environment but on the live production server this error comes up

after spending some time found one solution that work so I answer my own question,now am editing this question so can other users have better understanding about this issue .

Comment: Show some code. Are you using variables or parameters (e.g. the things starting with an `@`)? What is the default collation on the SQL Server instance?

Comment: thanks guys for negative vote, well I got the solution of my problem,issue is because of temp data base default collation type and my server collation type to be different .

Comment: @Utkarsh, I didn't downvote, but I guess I should. How do you expect people to help when you don't supply the required information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
i am getting the change to answer my own question
well the problem was related to collation type of databases,
in my proc i was useing temp tables by "create table #temptable" , 
now by some searching i found that #temptable is having the collation type of temp database which is different from my database, 
after changing the script to "select * into #temptable" ,I got that now #temptable is having same the collation as of my database, so that's how issue get resolved.
not sure this is the only reason behind the problem but it resolve my issue.
```